# Can I filter Google Sheets results by date and time relevent to current time?

Tags: datetime, filter, google-sheets

I have a  spreadsheet where sheet1 contains 1 text field of data and a date and time assigned to the data. On sheet 2 I need to have a filter that searches for an element in the text (using "=filter(sheet1!A1:A, search("search phrase", sheet1!A1:A))" to filter that part) but need to show only results where the time associated is for between 18hours - 3days before the current date and time. There is only one column of data other than the date and time, date and time is currently shown as "Date: 24.03.2013 11:04"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to create these formulas

```
=filter(Sheet1!A1:C, Sheet1!C1:C>minus(now(),3), Sheet1!C1:C<minus(now(),"12:00:00"))


=filter(importrange("Key","Sheet1!A1:C"), importrange("Key","Sheet1!C1:C")>minus(now(),3), importrange("Key","Sheet1!C1:C")<minus(now(),"12:00:00"))
```